# Jest instantiating empty objects instead of class instances

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest

I'm using ts-jest to test a JS/TS SDK/module. I'm running into a strange issue where a Jest test will run (no compile/import failures) but fail to correctly instantiate an object from the appropriate class.

```
test("Should build unit", () => {
  const builder = new UnitBuilder("TEST_UNIT");
  console.log(builder); // prints "{}"
  const unit = builder
    .addResource(...)
    .build();
  expect(unit.name).toBe("TEST_UNIT");
});
```

The test fails with: `TypeError: builder.addResource is not a function` since the instantiated object is empty. Here's the class in question:

```
export class UnitBuilder {
  constructor(templateId: string) {
    this.payload = {
      templateId,
      parameters: [],
    };
  }

  public addResource = (resource: CreateResourcePayload) => {
      // do stuff
  };

  public build = () => {
      // do stuff
  };

  public payload: CreateUnitPayload;
}
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the `jest` or `ts-jest` transpilation, e.g. babel, but perhaps it's something to do with the jest configuration as well?

`jest.config.ts`

```
import type { Config } from "@jest/types";

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json"],
  verbose: true,
  automock: true,
  testMatch: ["**/__tests/*.test.ts"],
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
  },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: Maybe you've created an incomplete mock for the module that exports the class, and jest is automatically using it?

Comment: It's a fairly new project, so there are currently no mocked libs/files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `automock: true` fixed the problem.